# There is a solution to make mysql select a varchar type as date?

Tags: mysql, date, varchar, between

I have column inside the database called `proxima_cal` and its `varchar(5)` that has a value like `11/16` that represent `month/year` and I need to select this table.

```
WHERE proxima_cal BETWEEN "11/16" AND "11/19"
```

as a varchar `BETWEEN` doesn't work so what I have to do to mysql conceder this column as date and get correct result ?

Comment: Maybe - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date ?

Comment: You should fix the problem by altering the table, adding **correctly** defined column and then populating it. Once you migrate the data, drop the varchar column, it makes absolutely 0 sense to use it, it even spends more storage space to store 5 characters compared to a `timestamp` column. Every other possible "solution" will be a hack.

Comment: @Mjh Not much help if it's a legacy system

Comment: @mikeyq6 - of course it is much help. Every other solution isn't a solution, it's a hack and will work limited amount of life of the application. Problems are either solved or not, sticking them under carpet doesn't make them solved. The actual solution is to change the data type and migrate current data. I know people work with legacy systems, but you could use that argument for every single thing out there and we'd never have anything working.

Comment: @Mjh I don't think telling people what they 'should' do is solving their problem. What if they aren't able to change the structure of the database?

Comment: @mikeyq6 that's why you have people, like you, who offer quick solutions that are fine for the moment and people like me, who are suggesting long-term solutions. I see no issue here, and I believe you're not saving dates as varchars, therefore you know how to use the tool. I'm helping the other person to use the tool correctly as well. What you think is not really relevant, like what I think is not really relevant. Fact is: OP is trying to use varchar as date and it's not working. We can have opinion on whatever, the fact is - you must use a date type for what he's trying to do.

Comment: @Mjh I guess we'll never agree. But that's ok. :)

Comment: Guys sorry for that .. but just more one thing that i want to say both of you are correct and vision if different ... in face there is 2 different vision of the problem .. 1 is what is the good environment for programming and other for frontend spirit. anyway i learn from both of you ... really thank you very much.

Comment: @mikeyq6 - well we do agree, you just have issues admitting it :) but still, you had to typecast the data into `date` format. So my question is - do you **actually** believe that it's good to store dates as (var)char if you intend to operate on the field? You don't have to answer, it's just to illustrate my point :)

Comment: @Mjh No, I don't think it's a good way of storing dates at all, that was never my point. My point is that we as developers, don't always have the time or access to recreate the systems we are working on, and need to find solutions to problems without rebuilding the system.

Comment: @mikeyq6 but this case is extremely trivial to fix, it can be done without even touching the code that inserts the data. Yes, we can't always fix crap, but when we can - we should. It takes around ~2 minutes to apply a fix to this problem forever. Anyway, we're getting into one of those pointless arguments. I suggested the permanent fix and I stand by it, but I'm not ordering OP to do it. Apparently, you think I was stating that. I'll excuse myself from the discussion, I gave you the upvote since you provided an accurate fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `STR_TO_DATE` method, something like:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', proxima_cal), '%d/%m/%y') BETWEEN '2016/11/01' AND '2019/11/01'
```

Comment: i changed the code because its `11-16` not `11/16` so i made like that `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', proxima_cal), '%d-%m-%y') BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2019-11-01'`